# Java servlet and a entity manager factory method for communicating mysql

Tags: java, servlets

I have a Java servlet and entity manager factory

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        this.setLevels(request);
```

if i use the line, then servlet does not work

```
//this.emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("projectPU");
```

servlet method continue...

```
        out.println("this is a html content ....");
    }
}
```

how to use Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("projectPU") in servlet? Thanks.

Comment: To start with, don't hand-write servlets; use a framework like Spring MVC that handles all of this for you already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hej,

if you do not want to use any frameworks, as suggested above, you can do it for example like that:

I created a class called DataBroker, this is the class which contains the EntityManager and can persist entities or send queries againt the database.

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class DataBroker<T> {

    private EntityManager em;

    public DataBroker() {
        if(em == null) {
            em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ProjectPU").createEntityManager();
        }
    }

    public void saveInput(T t) {
        em.merge(t);
    }


}
```

And now, for example a PersonServlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import de.professional_webworkx.database.DataBroker;
import de.professional_webworkx.model.Person;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/personServlet"})
public class PersonServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 318982491390578805L;

    private DataBroker<Person> dataBroker = new DataBroker<>();

    public PersonServlet() {
        super();
    }
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // do something with the user input from the jsp file
    }
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);
    }



}
```

But it's right, these frameworks handle all this for you and you can be focused on your business logic or what else ;)

Patrick